# Call function in buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm learning about buffer overflows and found a challenge that has a program somewhat like this:

```
int main() {
    do_something()
    return 0;
}

void do_something() {
    //get inputs
    printf("Did something.");
}

void do_something_else() {
    printf("Did something else.")
}
```

Assuming there was a buffer overflow in `do_something()`, how would I make it call the function `do_something_else()`?

Answer (score 9):

When a function is called, the compiler automatically pushes the value of saved return address onto the stack.
After that, it pushes the value of ebp onto the stack.

So when main calls do_something(), the values of saved eip, saved ebp will be pushed onto the stack in that order.

The saved eip will most probably be pointing to somewhere in the main(). If you overwrite that address with the address of do_something_else(), the do_something_else() function will be executed after do_something() is executed.

So your payload should look something like this:

"(bunch of A's or \x90's to reach ebp"+"BBBB(random value to fill ebp)"+"(address of do_something_else())"
Hope that helped.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking about is called shellcoding.  You can get an intro from http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html.  The basic idea is that you'll have `do_something`  read input into a fixed sized buffer.  Then you'll send more data into the buffer such that it overwrites the data on the stack, and if you write it just right you can make the spot that holds the return address point to `do_something_else`, so when `do_something` tries to return it will go where you want it to

You'll need to use a debugger to get the right address of the `do_something_else` function, and probably to get the real number of bytes you need to override the buffer by to get to the return address.